# Google Sheets API Error: invalid_user: Robot is missing a project number

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I am getting `invalid_user: Robot is missing a project number.` when trying to access google sheets using the service account created in my project.
I followed the exact steps mention in the URL: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

It seems to work for everyone else, and surprisingly I am not able to find any solution on the web.

Accessing the data using oAuth credentials is working good for me, but I want to deploy the code to AWS Lambda and hence need server to server access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was me replacing the client_email by my email ID. Rather, I should have shared the spreadsheet with the service account email ID!

Comment: Yep, this was my mistake. For everyone downloading a key from a service account, there is a `client_email` field that you should be using along with the `private_key`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by changing the scope value:

`scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']` to be replaced by `scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']`

I hope it helps you...

Comment: Did you change anything in the json provided by google as well? Apart from adding your email ID in client_email

Comment: It is working now. The problem was me replacing the client_email by my email ID. Rather, I should have shared the spreadsheet with the service account email ID.

Comment: ok cool ! I also remember I had to share my spreadsheet with the email Id crated by Google console