# Where to include 'project numer' in JWT send to googles oauth2 server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt

I am sending JWT and getting the response "Robot is missing a project number". It looks like I should place a project number somewhere in the JWT , but the question is where?

I am programming in C#.

```
long epoch = Epoch.EpochNow();

var header = "{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"alg\":\"HS256\",\"kid\":\"" + server_key + "\"}";
var claims = "{\"iss\":\"apps@le34.dk\",\"scope\":\"" + message_url + "\",\"aud\":\"" + audit_url + "\",\"exp\":"+ epoch + ",\"nbf\":" + (epoch+3600) + "," + project + "}";

var b64header = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header))
var b64claims = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(claims))

var payload = b64header + "." + b64claims;

byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("mPorwQB8kMDNQeeYO35KOrMMFn6rFVmbIohBphJPnp4=");
byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);

string sig = Convert.ToBase64String(HashHMAC(key, message))
return payload + "." + sig;
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199170/google-sheets-api-error-invalid-user-robot-is-missing-a-project-number you probably provide wrong scope

Comment: I have tried the solution there, but same result